# C# how to use Order by/sorting for a public class object

Tags: c#, sql-order-by

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. Hopefully I get a quick answer.

I have this public class ExcelValues which has inside a product array as well. Please see below the declaration:

```
public class ExcelValues
{
    public string SalesCompany;
    public string Customer;
    public string CustomerNr;
    public Product[] Products;
}

public class Product
{
    public string Code;
    public string Description;
    public string Category;
    public string Quantity;
    public string PVCVBlackWhite;
    public string PVCVColor;
    public string EndUserPriceEuro;
    public string EndUserPrice;
    public string DealerGPPercentage;
    public string DealerPriceEuro;

    //For Product Ordering;
    public string ProductOrder;
}
```

I am supposed to write the values into an excel file, but the ordering of the product doesn't come correct, so I add ProductOrder which has values 0,1,2 etc.

Now before using this excelvalues I want to sort the product rows by Product Order.

Any ideas?

I try the IEnumerable but the syntax gives me error:
code:

```
IEnumerable<Product> sortedProducts = outputVals.Products.OrderBy(Product => Product.ProductOrder);
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<KyoceraCL.Product>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<KyoceraCL.Product[]>'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Thanks in advance.
Sabby

Comment: @sstan: And I re-edited, because your rollback reverted the question to its original unclear state.  Check the actual original edit text.  The OP originally put `IEnumerable<Product>`, but didn't properly format it as code so the type parameter wasn't being displayed in the rendered question.

Comment: @David: Ah, that's not the first time I fall for that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Does the `sortedProducts` variable *need* to be of that *exact* type?  Or would this whole issue become moot with an implicit type?  `var sortedProducts = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface:

```
IEnumerable<Product> sortedProducts = outputVals.Products.OrderBy(Product => Product.ProductOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make a method to go through all the products and get the highest/lowest (depending on how you want to sort it) value of ProductOrder. And when you found the highest/lowest, then add it to a list in that order.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code with the generic IEnumerable you initially provided and it works as intended.. Sample I tested:

```
        ExcelValues outputVals = new ExcelValues();
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.ProductOrder = "a";
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.ProductOrder = "b";
        Product p3 = new Product();
        p3.ProductOrder = "c";
        outputVals.Products = new Product[] { p1, p3, p2 };
        IEnumerable sortedProducts = outputVals.Products.OrderBy(Product => Product.ProductOrder);
        //a, b, c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generic IEnumerable.

None generic IEnumerable is a collection of objects. It has the method GetEnumerator() which allows you to iterate through all of the `objects` in the enumerable.

An `IEnumerable<Type>` is basically a collection of the `Type` which is defined inside angular brackets `<Type>`. It has the method GetEnumerator() which allows you to iterate through all of the Type elements in the enumerable.

The second one is mostly recomended used because there is no need to cast and you always know about the type which the container has.
Also:

> IEnumerable is the base interface for all non-generic collections that can be enumerated. For the generic version of this interface see System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. IEnumerable contains a single method, GetEnumerator, which returns an IEnumerator. IEnumerator provides the ability to iterate through the collection by exposing a Current property and MoveNext and Reset methods.

For more information refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not reproduce the error you posted.

Instead, your *actual* code probably looks something like this instead:

```
IEnumerable<Product[]> sortedProducts = outputVals.Products.OrderBy(Product => Product.ProductOrder);
```

Just remove the square brackets to what you currently have posted, and you'll be ok.

*Note: Please be mindful of the formatting of your question, it can drastically change the meaning of your question, which is what happened here because the type parameters were not initially visible.*